# Is eventKit supported in IOS 3.0 

Tags: iphone

Is eventKit is not supported on 3.0 - it's giving me this message below on my 3.0 iPhone

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
>
> Referenced from:
> /var/mobile/Applications/B50DB029-19WE-481A-9090-3748EC4DD415/abc.app/abc
>
> Reason: image not found
>
> Data Formatters temporarily
> unavailable, will re-try after a
> 'continue'. (No memory available to
> program now: unsafe to call malloc)

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Appreciate it

Comment: -1, it took you more time to ask the question than looking it up in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventKit is introduced in 4.0 so you can't use it in prior OS version. You still can however run your application on old systems without functions provided by that framework. For that you must do the following:

1. In your target settings go to "Link Binary with Libraries" section and set link option for EventKit.framework to "Optional" (it is required by default) - that way you'll avoid loading library error
2. Perform run-time checks if eventkit apis are available to make sure that you won't call them on devices running 3.x OS

Answer (score 2):

EventKit was introduced in iOS 4.0.

Comment: so, its better to remove Eventkit?, my app wont work on version before of 4.0 rightt?????

Comment: In my opinion you don't need to worry much about supporting older versions of iOS. EventKit is a very useful library and the vast majority of your potential users will be running iOS 4.x.

Comment: yea, but bcoz of that, i am not able to move further, its giving me error, that i posted in my question. What do u suggest me to do, to override this issue.? Thanks